# Style dash in highchart graphic

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to change the line style of a chart, but I'm not getting it. I'm 
    looking to change the black line in the middle of the chart, to the style "DASH"

[image]

I already put the "dashStyle: 'dash'" in several places, but without success.

The example is the one of the [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bullet-graph)

Comment: This is why it fails: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/9pqmwcar/4/. It only sets the border `dashStyle`. I tried to create a working solution with paths, which works okay for the bar, but it messes up the target: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/qLfnp6cv/13/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to change the line style of a chart, but I'm not getting
>   it.

It is not possible because what you call line is actually an SVG **rectangle** element. That's why it can't be dashed.

However, you can achieve what you want by adding some custom logic and using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`. Simply remove default rectangle graphic of each series point and render several rectangles with breaks to create a **dashed line**. Check the code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
    inverted: true,
    marginLeft: 135,
    type: 'bullet',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          width = point.shapeArgs.height,
          height = point.shapeArgs.width,
          x = chart.plotLeft,
          xEnd = x + width,
          y = chart.plotTop + point.shapeArgs.x,
          dashWidth = 15,
          dashBreakWidth = 5,
          dashColor = '#000',
          dashElem,
          dashAmount,
          realDashBreakWidth;

        if (chart.dashedColl) {
          chart.dashedColl.forEach(function(oldDashElem) {
            oldDashElem.destroy();
          });
        }

        point.graphic.element.remove();
        chart.dashedColl = [];

        dashAmount = Math.floor(width / (dashWidth + dashBreakWidth));
        realDashBreakWidth = (width - dashAmount * dashWidth) / (dashAmount - 1);

        while (x < xEnd) {
          dashElem = chart.renderer.rect(x, y, dashWidth, height)
            .attr({
              fill: dashColor
            })
            .add()
            .toFront();

          chart.dashedColl.push(dashElem);

          x += dashWidth + realDashBreakWidth;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointPadding: 0.25,
      borderWidth: 0,
      color: 'red',
      targetOptions: {
        width: '200%'
      }
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7azfso1r/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#remove
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render